# Android with Google Cloud Messaging - device not being registered for some reason when I try to get its id

Tags: android

I have this standard code that runs when the user first runs the app:

```
    GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this);
    GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this);

    final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);
    if (regId.equals("")) 
    {
        GCMRegistrar.register(this, SENDER_ID);
    } 
    else 
    {
        Log.v(TAG, "Already registered");
    }
```

and the regId  is always empty which as I understand, means that the device is not registered.

But how do I make sure the device is registered?

Thanks!

EDIT:

Here is my manifest part about the cloud messaging:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.problemio"
    android:versionCode="82"
    android:versionName="2.2.82" >

    <supports-screens  android:largeScreens="true"   android:normalScreens="true"  android:smallScreens="true"/> 

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" android:targetSdkVersion="16"/>
    <!-- <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="xx"/>  -->

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <!-- Required permission to use in-app billing. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />



    <permission android:name="com.problemio.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" 
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.problemio.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />


    <!-- App receives GCM messages. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" /> 
    <!-- GCM requires a Google account. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <!-- Keeps the processor from sleeping when a message is received. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" /> 







    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:theme="@style/CustomTheme" 
        android:name="MyApplication"
        android:debuggable="true"
                >

        <!--  For Google Cloud Messaging -->
        <receiver android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
          <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <category android:name="com.problemio" />
          </intent-filter>
        </receiver>   

        <service android:name=".GCMIntentService" />
        <!--  End of Google Cloud Messaging -->
```

Comment: can you post your `permissions` from `manifest`

Comment: @Amandeep Jiddewar just posted it :)

Comment: `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" ` can you try changing this in your code, it's `4` in your case.

Comment: @Amandeep Jiddewar Someone told me that 4 or 8 should still work.  But yeah, I should try your suggestion.

Comment: @Amandeep Jiddewar also could it be the problem that I am testing on my own device to which I am installing the app from a usb connection by using commandline sdk tools?

Comment: Actually I would need a solution which supports version 4 because if those people upgrade the app and it no longer works for them, they might give me bad reviews.  Will setting it to 4 disable the app for the few people who have less than version 8?

Comment: it says you have to set it so because GCM does not support to all versions of android.

Comment: @Amandeep Jiddewar yeah but as I understand it, it will just not work on the earlier versions, but should have worked on my version.

Comment: GCM works on Android version 8 and above.