# Android - is there a way to make the app minSdkVersion="8" but still work on older versions?

Tags: android, android-manifest

I currently have this manifest setting:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" android:targetSdkVersion="16"/>
```

but I am trying to implement Google cloud messaging and it is only compatible with sdkVersion = 8

I looked at the breakdown of my users and here it is for the older versions:

```
Android 2.1 - 86
Android 3.0 - 11
Android 1.6 - 11
other - 7
```

I am not sure what other means. And I am also not sure how versions 4 or 8 refer to Android 2.1

Or is this apples and oranges? I am a bit confused.  The issue I am having is that I don't want users to upgrade the app and then have it not work on them.

Can this happen? Someone please clarify what is the better thing for me to do here.

Thanks!

Comment: http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html - that site shows a usage breakdown of the various android OS versions, but it also shows the API(or sdk) level. According to that site, 2.2 is api version 8 while the vast majority of your users appear to be on 2.1 (api level 7)

Comment: The [Android dashboard](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html) explains the relationship between API level (e.g., 4) and Android version (e.g., 1.6). I'm astounded that you have so many 1.6 users.

Comment: @nick ah I see, so essentially about 100 people will have their app disabled if I use cloud messaging? This is bad :( Is there any workaround?

Comment: @Ralgha's answer should work.

Comment: @nick but when I try it on my own phone which is a year old only, it doesn't work.  I also think his answer should work.  Maybe there is something else not right?

Comment: @Genadinik I'm not entirely sure. I haven't had to deal with stuff like this very much (yet). When I have, my solution has been to just up the minSdk version to whatever level I need. However, this sounds like it's not an option in your case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can enclose your GCM code in a check for the SDK level so it's only executed if the SDK is 8 or higher.

For example:

```
if ( android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 8 )
{
    // Do GCM Stuff here
}
```

Comment: yes this is what I thought at first. But if I leave the setting with version 8, then the device does not get registered. I posted about that here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12976930/android-with-google-cloud-messaging-device-not-being-registered-for-some-reaso but they say it is because I have version 8 :)

Comment: The only other way I can think of then is to use the multiple APK feature of the developer console.  Upload one APK with GCM for SDK >= 8 and another one without GCM for SDK < 8.  The Market will handle downloading the correct one for the user's device.  Unfortunately this means you'd have more work in maintaining two APKs.  
Were I to go this route, I'd stop working on the APK for < 8 (except for bug fixes) and only improve the higher one.  People have to upgrade eventually, SDK 7 is ancient, 4 is a fossil.